# Антивирус qihoo срабатывает на все приложения WPF

Tags: wpf, безопасность, virustotal

Я работаю в MVS2015 Community, и пользователи обнаружили что мой софт дает одно срабатывание на VirusTotal:

[Ссылка на вирустотал](https://www.virustotal.com/ru/file/771f5228410da37991365960b568edfe4ab1d0f1d479b20714f50919cf06f0f1/analysis/1447649081/)

> Qihoo-360 HEUR/QVM03.0.Malware.Gen

Я заинтересовался и стал искать причину. Но вот незадача, Qihoo срабатывает абсолютно на все приложения WPF, даже на хелловорлд. Даже на приложение,которое содержит только дизайн (создаем и сразу компилим).

Интересно, такое только у меня?

Comment: Так может в mvs вирус прокрался? Когда-то читал про то, что один вирус именно таким образом и размножался - попал вроде в крякнутую делфи и путешествовал по проектам. Плюс недавно был [похожий случай в appstore](http://www.bbc.com/russian/science/2015/09/150920_apple_store_bug)

Comment: Если антивирусы с хорошими базами, т.е. Касперский, clamav (drweb), avira и avz за вирус не считают - значит    у этого  qihoo ошибка в сигнатурах. У avast несколько лет назад была такая неприятная ошибка, сигнатура вируса подошла под драйвер tcpip в русских win98. В итоге как только обновились базы люди с win98 остались без сети и tcpip.sys приходилось на флешке приносить

Comment: вот поэтому я прошу всех счастливых обладателей 2015 студии попробовать скомпилить хелловорлд и отправить его на проверку. Это очень помогло бы разобраться.

Comment: Ложное срабатывание бывает у всех. Пишите вендору.

Comment: Понимаете, Владимир, мне всё-таки не чужда паранойя. А вдруг действительно что-то со студией?) У меня dr.Web, обновляемый, ну а вдруг что? как разобраться? Да и вендор китайский.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот антивирус действительно отличается ложными срабатываниями. Дело в том, что он основан на обучаемой нейросети. А нейросеть усвоила, что программы без манифеста, ресурса версий, иконки(и т.п.) как правило являются сгенерированными вирусом. Выходом может быть добавление в файл вышеуказанных ресурсов. Увеличение размера кода может так же решить проблему, потому что генерируемые распаковщики, как правило, используют довольно маленькие секции для кода(равные по размеру файловому выравниванию в файле).

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант добавлять exeшник в исключения для антивируса, или же сменить антивирус. Некоторое время назад была такая же проблема с касперским, решал отключением антивируса на время работы

Comment: приложение простейшее, поэтому пользователи относятся с подозрением к любым срабатываниям. Их быть не должно. Приложение вообще никаких операций вне своего каталога не совершает.

Comment: пришла идея еще подпись для сборки добавить, ну или обращаться к разработчикам антивируса. Да в том то и дело что это ложные срабатывания старая проблема, а must read рекомендаций данной проблемы нет, все от случая к случаю.